# Image resizing in Responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Responsive web design resizes images to the mobile device’s screen. The full image is downloaded on a mobile device and resized to fit the screen. This consumes unnecessary CPU and RAM. Is there any alternative way ?

Comment: also try to use as few images as you can.  You can do a lot with css alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what your looking for is "Adaptive Images". Essentially serving smaller images based on the device / viewport.

There is quite a lot of talk about this recently but I guess here is one place you can get started:

http://adaptive-images.com/

This would use a server side approach. PHP in this case.

These articles are good to get a general idea of the current situation:

- http://filamentgroup.com/lab/rwd_img_compression/
- http://blog.netvlies.nl/design-interactie/retina-revolution/

Hope that helps.